# Archivo bat no funciona correctamente

Tags: windows, cmd

Sobre el cmd de windows 10 he creado un archivo bat con el siguiente código pero no me va y no se porque

```
@echo off

set /p var = "hola: "

if  "%var%" == "hola" (

    echo correcto

    GOTO fin

)

echo incorrecto

:fin

echo fin

pause
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que es lo que quieres hacer? Y en tal caso el archivo debe ser .bat

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con: *no me va*? Si te da un error deberías mostrarlo para entender el problema. Saludos

Comment: Dejame ver si entiendo, si introduces "hola" se debe cerrar el bat. en caso contrario, debe salir incorrecto, ¿Verdad?

Comment: @pipo recuerda marcar tu pregunta como respondida si se respondió tu pregunta correctamente

Answer (score 7):

Estimado, tienes errores de tipeo y sintaxis en algunos sectores, te dejo tu ejemplo funcionando de forma correcta:

Explicaciones con comentarios en el bloque de código #:

```
     @echo off
    #las variables y los textos no deben ir entre comillas
    :inicio
    set/p var=hola:
    echo.
    #El IF no lleva parentesis, sino que se direcciona con "goto" donde quieres ir.
    if %var%==hola goto correcto else goto fin
    #La comparación se realiza con el valor de la variable y con el texto sin comillas 
    #Añadí adicionalmente un pause en cada resultado para ver donde cae tu respuesta
    :fin
    echo incorrecto
    pause
    exit

    :correcto
    echo correcto
    pause
    exit
```

Si tienes dudas, no olvides preguntar.

Comment: Está perfecto. :)

Comment: Gracias, todo por ayudar a un colega.

Comment: harifo gracias por responder pero a parte del codigo arreglado seria conveniente explicar cada fallo o al menos enumerarlos para no tener que comparar un codigo y otro

Comment: @lois6b añadí los comentarios para explicar el código y lo que le falta por implementar.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo. y en caso de que el archivo no este funcionando como se puede regenerar o recuperar. Ya que, tengo un programa o archivo .BAT que es de una maquina cortadora de vidrios el cual funcionaba y despues de un tiempo para aca no ejecuta los enlaces del menu. Es posible recuperar su funcionalidad?. Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/378508)

Comment: Hola Orlando, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, 
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score -3):

El problema es en esta linea. `if "%var%" == "hola" ( echo correcto GOTO fin ) echo incorrecto`

La variable  var la pusiste entre comillas **"%var%"** y lo tienes que poner con comillas MAS UNOS CORCHETES **["%var%"]**

Código Final con algunos arreglos:

```
@echo off
title EJEMPLO
set/p var = "hola: "

if ["%var%"]=="123" (
goto bien

)ELSE (
goto mal
)

:bien
echo bien
pause

:mal
echo mal
pause
```

Comment: No, esto está mal. Porque al presionar 123 sale "mal"